# Map#replaceAll - How to change key, not only value?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Having HashMap of type `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`

want to update all key value pairs of Map within main Map. `getList` is method which returns `List<Integer>` after adding value.

```
mainMap.get(idx).replaceAll((k, v) -> getList(curr, v));
```

How can I update `k` too in above code ? Increase the value by 1

Comment: Why not just `mainMap.put(idx, <new map as new value>)` (or `mainMap.replace(idx,...)` with a new map having new keys and values)?

Comment: You can't. `replaceAll()` can only modify the values.

Comment: so Incrementing key by one and and adding value in List..is not modifying ?

Comment: First of all, the assignment to `v` is obsolete and confusing to readers of the code. `v` is a *parameter* and assigning to a parameter has no persisting effect. Just use `replaceAll((k, v) ->getList(curr, v))` as the result of the expression will be used as new value by contract. Second, changing a key always is a structural change to the map, removing the old key and adding a new key. This can’t be done while iterating over the map.

Comment: By the way, your assignment to `v` is obsolete and has no effect. Remove the `v = `. You are supposed to return your new value, not assign it.

Comment: but in docs its no where mention that, replaceAll will only replace values but not keys ..

Comment: The docs are pretty clear. It wants you to give it a `BiFunction<K, V, V>` that, given the `key` and `value`, return a **new value** for the given key. It never says anything about returning a new key as well. Note the last generic type which is `V` as well, i.e. a value. It is not something like `BiFunction<K, V, Entry<K, V>>` or similar.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.BiFunction)) says: “*Replaces each entry's **value** with the result of invoking the given function on that entry until all entries have been processed or the function throws an exception.*” A clearly stated purpose. You could fill books with what the method will not do.

Comment: Is there any way I could update key and value both, because in my inner Map, there is going to be only one entry ?

Comment: @AshishJangra Many. But not with `replaceAll`.

Comment: Sounds like the `Map` is the wrong tool for the purpose to begin with. Why don’t you use a class having two properties, an `Integer` and a `List<Integer>`. Maybe, you actually want an `int` for the first property. Then, updating it ill be easy.

Comment: You can use `mainMap.compute(idx, (k, v) -> { ... })` to construct a new map which will replace the existing value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
mainMap.compute(idx, (k, v) -> v.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getKey() + 1,
        e -> getList(curr, e.getValue()))));
```